# Why does grep match more than it should, e.g. "^[\s]*set breakpoint.*in" matches "set breakpoint 1 at main.c:5"?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

### patterns.txt

```
^[\s]*set breakpoint.*if
^[\s]*set breakpoint.*in
^[\s]*set breakpoint.*skip
```

### script.txt

```
set breakpoint 1 at main.c:5
set breakpoint 2 at main.c:6
set breakpoint 3 at main.c:7
set breakpoint 4 if
```

### Examples and Unexpected Results

When I run `cat "${script.txt}" | grep -f patterns.txt` the result is:

```
set breakpoint 1 at main.c:5 // WHY DOES THIS MATCH???
set breakpoint 2 at main.c:6 // WHY DOES THIS MATCH???
set breakpoint 3 at main.c:7 // WHY DOES THIS MATCH???
set breakpoint 4 if
```

Same goes for:

```
cat "${script.txt}" | grep -E '^[\s]*set breakpoint.*if|^[\s]*set breakpoint.*in|^[\s]*set breakpoint.*skip'
```

Comment: Because this match: `^[\s]*set breakpoint.*in`

Comment: Because of the "in" in "main".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `breakpoint.*in` matches `breakpoint <digit> at main` in first 3 lines (`main` is ending with `in`).

You should use end anchor in your pattern as this:

```
cat patterns.txt
^\s*set breakpoint.*if$
^s\s*et breakpoint.*in$
^s\s*et breakpoint.*skip$
```

Or else:

```
^\s*set breakpoint.*i[fn]$
^s\s*et breakpoint.*skip$
```

Answer (score 2):

### Greedy Expressions

> ^[\s]*set breakpoint.*in

Your regex is too greedy. `.*` is often the problem, because it will consume as much as possible, which includes the "in" in "main". You need a less-greedy expression, as well as a more-exact pattern.

### Use Word-Boundaries

One way to make your expression less greedy is to have the pattern match a word boundary with the `\b` atom. For example, add word-boundaries before your keywords in in patterns.txt as follows:

```
^[\s]*set breakpoint.*\bif
^[\s]*set breakpoint.*\bin
^[\s]*set breakpoint.*\bskip
```

Then when you run extended grep, you will get only the output you are probably be expecting:

```
$ egrep -f pattern.txt script.txt 
set breakpoint 4 if
```

Comment: Very useful tip with word boundaries. Thank you!